# Get polymer parent element

Tags: javascript, polymer

So I've been using Polymer for about a day now and I'm having trouble phrasing this question, so if my approach is way off base, please don't feel the need to fix this, rather point me in the right direction.

What I have are custom elements within custom elements and I would like a child element to affect the parent's attributes.  The approach I'm taking is to create a click handler, closing the parent element in an IIFE, then passing that handler to the sub component. Like so...

```
Polymer({
  ready: function(){
     this.superHandler = (function(p) {
        return function() {
          // "this" here will be the sub-component
          p.title = this.title;
        }
     })(this);
  }
});
```

Where the parent element uses it in it's template like...

```
<polymer-element name="parent-element">
  <template>
    <sub-element on-click={{superHandler}} />
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

This (in my real code, though it's possible there's typos here) works in everything but IE, and I know IE isn't officially supported, but it's so close I don't want to give up on it.  Things I want to avoid are repeated references to parentNodes and shadowRoots to get to the parent I'm looking for.

**Edit**

I forgot to mention how it's failing in IE, and why I want to avoid the parentNode call.  In IE, when it goes to dispatch the event specifically line 9131 of polymer.js, the variable "method" and the reference in obj[method] are strings in IE, and so have no method apply.  The reason I want to avoid the parentNode is because the caller isn't the direct parent, so I don't want to keep getting parentNodes until I find the right one, since the code is much more understandable when I can name the variable.

**Edit 2**

What I'm going with now (since it's working in IE9), though I'm leaving the question open for a better answer is to continue with the IIFE, returning a function that takes an argument that is the child.  Then the child will find the parent of interest by a querySelector.  This means the child has to have fore-knowledge of the parent and the method to call, which isn't ideal, but... IE.

So the parent sets it up as...

```
Polymer('parent-element', {
  ready: function(){
     this.superHandler = (function(p) {
        return function(child) {
          p.title = chile.title;
        }
     })(this);
  }
});
```

And the child must get it by a query selector, say by 'parent-element' and know the name 'superHandler' (not the actual name)

```
Polymer('child-element',{
        clickHandler: function(){
            var p = document.querySelector('parent-element').superHandler;
            p(this);
        }
    });
```

Better ideas?

Comment: Not sure what the use case is but, note that if you pass a published attribute of the parent down to the child THEN if the child modified the attribute, the parent's attributeChanged function (if you have one in place) will automatically be called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the custom event suggestions.  That got me to go back and look at the core elements again to find [this](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/core-signals.html).

Then I just need to add a

```
<core-signals on-core-signal-my-event="{{myEventHandler}}"></core-signals>
```

Fire off a "core-signal" event with a name of (in this example) "my-event" and create a method "myEventHandler" on the parent e.g.

```
Polymer({
  myEventHandler: function(e,detail,sender) {...}
})
```

Comment: In Polymer 1.0 core-signals was renamed to iron-signals. Please also note (copy from iron-signals docs): avoid using iron-signals whenever you can use a controller (parent element) to mediate communication instead.

Answer (score 16):

You can use own events to pass data between elements.

Parent component:

```
<polymer-element name="parent-element">
  <template>
    <!-- ... -->
    <sub-element></sub-element>
  </template>
  <script>
  Polymer({
    ready: function() {
      this.addEventListener('eventFromChild', this.myAction);
    },
    myAction: function(event) {
      console.log(event.detail);
    },
  });
  </script>
```

Child component:

```
<polymer-element name="sub-element" attributes="foo bar">
  <template>
    <!-- ... -->
    <button on-click="{{passParams}}">Send</button>
  </template>
  <script>
  Polymer({
    ready: function() {
      this.foo = 'abc';
      this.bar = '123';
    },
    passParams: function() {
      this.fire('eventFromChild', { foo: this.foo, bar: this.bar });
    },
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple way to get access to the parent element in Javascript. This works in [a personal work](https://github.com/bdulac/polymeria/blob/master/uml-element.html) (polymer 0.5 - as mentioned in the comments, things are different in 1.0). Not tested on IE, but it seems to me a simple solution:

```
Polymer('sub-element', {
  ready: function(){
     this.parentNode;
  }
});
```

Comment: In my projet, this.parentNode was not working in polymer, as I was at the root of the shadow DOM. To access the component parent, I had to use : this.host.parentNode

Comment: In Polymer 1.0 `this.parentNode` will get the parent web component.

Comment: In Polymer 1.0 this.parentNode does not get the parent web component. Suppose your child web component is wrapped in a <p>. You will get a <p> as the parent node. It seems it would be impossible to have a general way to do this. Bubbled events may be the only way to communicate in a general fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the nature of a component, I'm hesitant to access the parentNode in this way. If you need styling you can do without it by using the `:host()` css rules. IMHO, it seems icky to reach out to the parent element unless you have a good reason. Why not use a custom event or an intermediary store like `localStorage`?

Also check out ["The 'Gold Standard' Checklist for Web Components"](https://github.com/webcomponents/gold-standard/wiki) for additional help on best practices.

Comment: That's just a great list to have around regardless. Thanks for the link, and yes I agree a custom event is the way to go.  Once I started down the path of passing the function down I got fixated.

Comment: Very cool Felix.  Do we feel one of these answers is correct then? Or do we need more testing? Let me know if I can help any further. Thanks.